# Insert a document into another document in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-collection

I'm trying to add a document in another document.

[image]

I am trying to insert a new document with a timestamp as a key and light prox and temp as the content of that document into document `sensor_collection`.

It's logical that my code doesn't work, because I'm setting a new `sensor_collection`. Does anyone know how I can set a timestamp document in `sensor_collection` or is it adviced not to do it this way?

This is the code:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection  =  db.getCollection(Sensor.KEY_COLLECTION);
    //append sensor data to existing document
    collection.updateOne(doc, new Document("$set",
            new Document("sensor_collection", new Document(
                    String.valueOf(stamp.getCurrentTime()), new Document(
                            Sensor.KEY_LIGHT, sensorData.getLight())
                            .append(Sensor.KEY_PROX, sensorData.getProx())
                            .append(Sensor.KEY_TEMP, sensorData.getTemp())
                    ))));
```

Currently this code overrides the timestamp that's already in the db.

Comment: I'm kinda lost. do you want to append your new doc to existing set?

Comment: Hey, in sensor_collection I want to have multiple timestamps each containing light, prox and temp. And I want to add another timestamp object to sensor_collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the Mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) I found this:

"To specify a `<field>` in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation."

I used the $set operator. And I'm setting sensor_collection.timestamp

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection  =  db.getCollection(Sensor.KEY_COLLECTION);
    //append sensor data to existing document
    collection.updateOne(doc, new Document("$set",
            new Document("sensor_collection."+String.valueOf(stamp.getCurrentTime()),
                     new Document(
                            Sensor.KEY_LIGHT, sensorData.getLight())
                            .append(Sensor.KEY_PROX, sensorData.getProx())
                            .append(Sensor.KEY_TEMP, sensorData.getTemp())
                    )));
```

This works. Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to an existing embedded collection, use `$push` instead of `$set`. The `$push` operator appends a specified value to an array. Something like this:

```
collection.updateOne(doc, new Document("$push",
            new Document("sensor_collection", new Document(
                    String.valueOf(stamp.getCurrentTime()), new Document(
                            Sensor.KEY_LIGHT, sensorData.getLight())
                            .append(Sensor.KEY_PROX, sensorData.getProx())
                            .append(Sensor.KEY_TEMP, sensorData.getTemp())
                    ))));
```

For more details on mongo's update operators, [check this out](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. $push works if sensor_collection was an array. It's an object. Is it still possible to add another timestamp object to sensor_collection? Without using array's. Or is using arrays the more common approach?

Comment: You could select the embedded collection instead of whole collection and just update that. may be this works but using an array would be simpler i guess